# Probability of within $\pm\, \sigma$

Tags: probability

A rock is dropped from rest from a height $h$. As it falls, photographs are taken at random intervals.  What is the probability that a photograph, selected at random, would show a distance $x$ more than one standard deviation away from the average?

The probability density is $\rho (x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}\,\,0 \leq x \leq h$.
One standard deviation from the average is $ \langle x \rangle \pm \, 1 \sigma$, $\langle x \rangle$ denoting the average.  We want $P(x > \langle x \rangle \pm \sigma)$.  Splitting this up: $$P(x > \langle x \rangle \pm \sigma) = P(x > \langle x \rangle + \sigma) + P(x > \langle x \rangle - \sigma)$$
I believe this can be recast as: $$P(x > \langle x \rangle \pm \sigma) = (1 - P( x \leq \langle x \rangle + \sigma)) + (1- P(x \leq \langle x \rangle - \sigma))$$

So the probability is $$P = \left(1 - \int_{0}^{\langle x \rangle + \sigma} \rho (x) dx\right) + \left(1-\int_{0}^{\langle x \rangle - \sigma} \rho (x) dx\right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: what do you mean by average?  half of the height or half from the falling time or something else?

Comment: More like $\displaystyle P = \left(1 - \int_{0}^{\langle x \rangle + \sigma} \rho (x) dx\right) + \left(\int_{0}^{\langle x \rangle - \sigma} \rho (x) dx\right)$ or $\displaystyle P = 1-  \int_{\langle x \rangle - \sigma} ^{\langle x \rangle + \sigma} \rho (x) dx $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. I will denote $<x>$ by $\mu$

The probability that the distance is more than one standard deviation away from the average is $P(x < \mu - \sigma) + P(x > \mu + \sigma)$ (note the direction of the inequality signs). To see this, take as an example the normal distribution from the picture below. Then think of $x$ as a real life object. To be more than one standard deviation away from $\mu$, $x$ should be smaller than $\mu -\sigma$ (the area shaded in red) or larger than $\mu + \sigma$ (the area shaded in black).

Since you are given a PDF, you do not need to write those probabilities in the standard form $P(X<a)$ (where $a$ is a constant). This would only be useful if you were only given the CDF.

In this case the probabilities can be written as: $$P(x < \mu - \sigma) + P(x > \mu + \sigma)=\int_0^{\mu - \sigma}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}dx + \int_{\mu + \sigma}^h\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}dx$$

[image: example]

Comment: @CAF No problem, glad I could be of help :)